# Magento: set up FedEx shipping, but it's still now available for users

Tags: magento, fedex

Have set up the FedEx account in Magento, but when trying to checkout I'm getting:

> This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.

Found this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6996/P0/
Currency is USD, ZIP is 10033 (looks fine)

They advice:

```
// find:
$responseBody = curl_exec($ch);

// add:
Mage::log($responseBody);
```

Tried that, but got no error! Here's the answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FDXRateAvailableServicesReply xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ReplyHeader></ReplyHeader>
<Entry>
<Service>GROUNDHOMEDELIVERY</Service>
<Packaging>YOURPACKAGING</Packaging>
<TimeInTransit>1</TimeInTransit>
<EstimatedCharges>
<DimWeightUsed>false</DimWeightUsed>
<BilledWeight>10.0</BilledWeight>
<DiscountedCharges>
<BaseCharge>6.86</BaseCharge>
<TotalDiscount>0.00</TotalDiscount>
<TotalSurcharge>3.24</TotalSurcharge>
<NetCharge>10.10</NetCharge>
<EarnedDiscount>0.00</EarnedDiscount>
</DiscountedCharges>
</EstimatedCharges>
<SignatureOption>NONE</SignatureOption>
</Entry>
<Entry>
<Service>FEDEXGROUND</Service>
<Packaging>YOURPACKAGING</Packaging>
<TimeInTransit>1</TimeInTransit>
<EstimatedCharges>
<DimWeightUsed>false</DimWeightUsed>
<BilledWeight>10.0</BilledWeight>
<DiscountedCharges>
<BaseCharge>6.86</BaseCharge>
<TotalDiscount>0.00</TotalDiscount>
<TotalSurcharge>3.56</TotalSurcharge>
<NetCharge>10.42</NetCharge>
<EarnedDiscount>0.00</EarnedDiscount>
</DiscountedCharges>
</EstimatedCharges>
<SignatureOption>NONE</SignatureOption>
</Entry>
</FDXRateAvailableServicesReply>
```

So, it gets the quotes, but still says "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us." at frontend.

Where to look next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, was messing with this for hours, but answered my own question right after I posted it here.

That's what it was all about: FedEx gives me two entries (see XML in O-post).
Here are GROUNDHOMEDELIVERY and FEDEXGROUND.
There's a bunch of options at the backend:

```
Priority Overnight
Standard Overnight
First Overnight
2Day
Express Saver
International Priority
International Economy
International First
1 Day Freight
2 Day Freight
3 Day Freight
Ground
Home Delivery
Intl Priority Freight
Intl Economy Freight
Europe First Priority
```

Selected ones were only Priority Overnight and First Overnight. Thy're not listed in answer (remember, only GROUNDHOMEDELIVERY and FEDEXGROUND). I've chosen 'Home Delivery' and it showed the quotes at the frontend!

Why doesn't FedEx doesn't give all the specter (maybe it depends on zip code or something should be done at the FedEx account) - that's another question. This one is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Magento log and report directory. Might be FedEx data format changed or magento sends wrong data.